# add- and removeClass on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I don't see why this doesn't work - any help?
I want it to pop up as I hover over the .hoveroverme div

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hoveroverme").hover(
    function(){
$('.popupbox').addClass('popupnobox');},
    function(){
$('.popupbox').removeClass('popupnobox'); }
);
```

CSS

```
.popupnobox{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 100;
}

.popupbox{
    background-color:magenta;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:2px solid black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.hoveroverme{
    background-color:green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="hoveroverme">Hover Over Me!</div>
<div class="popupbox"></div>
```

Comment: @Donald has answer I guess, why it doesn't work. You're adding same class and removing that same class again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have defined the `popupnobox` css class other way round. As per my understanding; initially `popupbox` should be invisible and whenever we hover over the `hoveroverme`; then only it should be made visible as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".hoveroverme").hover(
        function() {
          $('.popupbox').addClass('popupnobox');
        },
        function() {
          $('.popupbox').removeClass('popupnobox');
        }
      );
  });
```

```css
.popupnobox {
  visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 100;
}
.popupbox {
  background-color: magenta;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hoveroverme {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoveroverme">Hover Over Me!</div>
<div class="popupbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hoveroverme").on("hover",
    function(){
$('.popupbox').addClass('popupnobox');},
    function(){
$('.popupbox').removeClass('popupnobox'); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion Better use `id` is not disturb with the `class`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".hoveroverme").hover(
        function() {
          $('#popupbox').addClass('popupnobox');
        },
        function() {
          $('#popupbox').removeClass('popupnobox');
        }
      );
  });
```

```css
.popupnobox {
  visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 100;
}
.popupbox {
  background-color: magenta;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hoveroverme {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoveroverme">Hover Over Me!</div>
<div class="popupbox" id="popupbox"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JQuery script is incorrect, please see this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/hmajid/pen/EgALoB?editors=0010/)

Code:

HTML

```
<div class="hoveroverme">Hover Over Me!</div>
<div class="popupbox"></div>
```

CSS

```
.popupnobox{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 100;
}

.popupbox{
    background-color:magenta;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:2px solid black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.hoveroverme{
    background-color:green;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hoveroverme").hover(
    function(){
$('.popupbox').addClass('popupnobox');
    },
    function(){
$('.popupbox').removeClass('popupnobox');
    });
 });
```